# Why does Abaqus not find my c++ compiler?

Tags: c++, windows, abaqus

I need to use uMat and user subroutines in Abaqus.
I installed Abaqus 2020, Visual Studio 2019, Intel oneApi Base Toolkit and Intel oneApi HPC Toolkit (in this order). After successfully linking the Fortran Compiler (Intel Fortran Compiler 2021.4) with VS19 (setting all the path variables and editing the abaqus2020.bat and the abaqus_v6.env) I started Abaqus Command (as admin) and used the command `abaqus verify -user ..` it PASSED right away.

My main problem is: if I plug in "abaqus info=system" everything is fine except the C++ Compiler.

```
C++ Compiler: Unable to locate or determine the version of a C++ compiler on this
system. If a C++ compiler is installed on this system, please load vcvars64.bat
file before running Abaqus
```

I tried:

- different versions of VS
- different OS
- different Processor
- calling the vcvars64.bat in abaqus2020.bat
- Installing third party c++ compilers (MinGW)

My current setup:

- Processor: AMD Ryzen 5 3600
- RAM: 32 GB DDR4 3200
- Graphics: MSI NVidea Geforce GTX 1660 Ti
- OS: Windows 11
- Linker Version: Microsoft Incremental Linker Version 14.29.30137.0
- Fortran Compiler: Intel Fortran Compiler 2021.4 MPI MS-MPI 9.0.12497.11

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKX1n.png)

Comment: Did you actually do what is asked, ie loading vcvars64.bat before calling abaqus bat? That sets up the necessary environment variables. You can also find it in the start menu as "visual studio 2019 commandline" or somesuch.

Comment: How are you running these batch files? You can't click on them in the windows file manager. You need to run everything in the same cmd.exe window with vcvars64.bat run first. Or like @Botje mentioned just use a Visual Studio 2019 x64 native tools command prompt and do everything from that. If this does not work verify that you installed the native c++ development in the VS Installer. I don't think its always selected by default.

Comment: Hey guys - thanks for your quick replies.
I started Abaqus command (as admin) - i wrote "abaqus info=system" which automatically runs various batch files. I added a call to vcvars64.bat to the first batch - so it is executed right before abaqus itself starts gathering the system info. I installed visual studio 2019 professional now and selected the "desktop with c++" - The Intel(R) C++ compilers are also included (those are also selected in the instructions)

Could my processor be the main issue here? I don`t know if AMD can run the Intel compiler right away.